# SQL Server 2008, how to count distinct values that change

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have entities that have 2 answers y/n.

I need to count the number of entities who change answers from 'n' to 'y' between stage1 and stage2.

```
entity || answer || stage
    a  ||   y    ||  1
    a  ||   n    ||  2
    b  ||   y    ||  1
    b  ||   y    ||  2
    c  ||   n    ||  1
    c  ||   n    ||  1 
    d  ||   n    ||  1
    d  ||   y    ||  2
```

I tried this but this doesn't work (because it counts all entities who change answers)

```
select 
    entity, count(distinct answer)
from 
    myDB
where 
    stage between '1' and '2'
group by 
    entity, answer
```

but I don't understand why this doesn't work, the result comes out all O's

```
select 
    entity, 
    case 
       when stage = '1' and answer = 'n' and 
            stage = '2' and answer = 'y' then 1
       else 0 
    end as 'result'
from 
    myDB 
where 
    stage between '1' and '2'
group by 
    entity, stage, answer
```

Comment: are those twp separate columns or single column?

Comment: You can't have two columns with the same name...

Comment: sorry, sigle column. I made it look like two columns...

Comment: Is `c  ||   n    ||  1` appearing twice a mistake? Should the other line be for stage 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) 
from myDB s2
where 
    s2.stage ='2' and s2.answer='y'
    and exists (select * from myDB s1 
                 where s1.entity=s2.entity 
                 and s1.stage ='1' and s1.answer='n'
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select     count(*) 

 from      (select      1 as x
            from        myDB 
            where       stage in (1,2)
            group by    entity
            having      min(case when stage = 1 then answer end) = 'n' 
                    and max(case when stage = 2 then answer end) = 'y'
            ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  count(*)
from    (select entity,stage,answer from myDB) t
            pivot (max(answer) for stage in([1],[2])) p
where   [1] = 'n' and [2] = 'y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    count(*)
from 
    [myDb] as [s1] 
inner join 
    [myDb] as [s2] 
on 
        [s1].[entity]   =   [s2].[entity] 
    and [s1].[answer]   =   'n'
    and [s1].[stage]    =   1
    and [s2].[answer]   =   'y' 
    and [s2].[stage]    =   2;
```

**But, it works with your provided data only.**
If your have duplicated enities, it does not works, because at this case there is not impossible to identify uniqueness of entity. You need additional data then.

```
a   y   1
a   n   2
b   y   1
b   y   2
c   n   1
c   n   2
d   n   1
d   y   2
d   n   1
d   y   2
```

**Lets make assumption, that same logical entity values are stored one after another. Then you can handle this by using this query:**

```
declare @myDB TABLE
(
     [rec_id]   int         identity(1, 1)  
    ,[entity]   varchar(10)
    ,[answer]   varchar(10)
    ,[stage]    int
);


insert into @myDB
(   
     [entity]
    ,[answer]
    ,[stage]
)
select
     [entity]
    ,[answer]
    ,[stage]
from
    [myDB];


select 
     [s1].[entity]
    ,count([s1].[entity])
from 
    @myDB as [s1] 
inner join 
    @myDB as [s2] 
on 
        [s1].[entity]   =   [s2].[entity] 
    and [s1].[answer]   =   'n'
    and [s1].[stage]    =   1
    and [s2].[answer]   =   'y' 
    and [s2].[stage]    =   2
    and [s1].[rec_id]   =   [s2].[rec_id] - 1
group by
    [s1].[entity];
```